# Excel VBA run-time error 91 can't solve

Tags: excel, runtime-error, excel-2010, vba

I'm trying to pull data from website with XML. Look at my script below:

Script

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub btnRefresh_Click()
    Dim req As New XMLHTTP
    Dim resp As New DOMDocument
    Dim weather As IXMLDOMNode
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Dim wshape As Shape
    Dim thiscell As Range
    Dim i As Integer

    req.Open "GET", "http://api.worldweatheronline.com/premium/v1/weather.ashx?key=myConfidentialToken&q=Baku&format=xml&num_of_days=5"
    req.send

    resp.LoadXML req.responseText

    For Each weather In resp.getElementsByTagName("weather")
        i = i + 1
        ws.Range("theDate").Cells(1, i).Value = weather.SelectNodes("date")(0).Text
        ws.Range("highTemps").Cells(1, i).Value = weather.SelectNodes("maxtempC")(0).Text
        ws.Range("lowTemps").Cells(1, i).Value = weather.SelectNodes("mintempC")(0).Text
        Set thiscell = ws.Range("weatherPicture").Cells(1, i)
        Set wshape = ws.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, thiscell.Left, thiscell.Top, thiscell.Width, thiscell.Height)
        wshape.Fill.UserPicture weather.SelectNodes("weatherIconUrl").Item(0).Text
    Next weather

End Sub
```

This script returns run-time error 91. It says: "Object variable or With block variable not set". When I debug, running stops at the line before "next weather" statement. Why this script returns such an error, while I've already set my "wshape" variable?

Comment: probably the error occures in the line before - Set wshape = ws.Shapes...

Comment: That line works correctly and adds rectangular shape to "thiscell". Problem is in the "wshape.Fill..." line.

Comment: I suspect that `weather.SelectNodes("weatherIconUrl")..` is returning nothing, so the attempt to get item(0).text is failing. Create a variant and set the variant to that object first, then check if it is Nothing (`Debug.Print TypeName(...)` is useful)

Comment: so wshape is surely an object?

Comment: No it returns XML response and fills "theDate", "highTemps", "lowTemps" cells correctly.

Comment: @niyou yes, it is shape object. Look at the re-edited version of script.

Comment: that was not my question. while you are debugging you are sure wshape contains an object?

Comment: What is in `weather.SelectNodes("weatherIconUrl").Item(0).Text` ? (file name expected)

Comment: Yes @PatrickHonorez that part of the statement is most probably where the problem lies.

Comment: @PatrickHonorez "weatherIconUrl" is a tag inside returned XML file and it contains url address of image. If you wish, I can add XML response in my question.

Comment: Checking the WorldWeatherOnline documentation it seems that the element <weatherIconUrl> is a sub-element of either <current_condition> or <hourly> elements, not a direct child of <weather>, so is seems likely you will get an empty set back from `weather.SelectNodes("weatherIconUrl")`.

Comment: You could try `.SelectNodes("//weatherIconUrl")` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @JohnRC pointed, there are the set of `<hourly>` nodes inside each `<weather>` node, and each `<hourly>` node in turn contains `<weatherIconUrl>`. You may save the response XML to a file, and use any online XML tree viewer to look into a structure:

[image: XML tree viewer]

Take a look at the below example, there is a nested loop added to get `<weatherIconUrl>` from each `<hourly>` node:

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub btnRefresh_Click()

    Dim oReq As Object
    Dim sResp As String
    Dim oDoc As Object
    Dim oData As Object
    Dim cDays As Object
    Dim oDay As Object
    Dim cHours As Object
    Dim oHour As Object

    Set oReq = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    oReq.Open "GET", "http://api.worldweatheronline.com/premium/v1/weather.ashx?key=e11be04676ad49038f9175720181600&q=saint-petersburg&format=xml&num_of_days=5", False
    oReq.Send
    sResp = oReq.ResponseText
    Set oDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
    oDoc.LoadXML sResp
    Set oData = oDoc.getElementsByTagName("data")(0)
    Set cDays = oData.SelectNodes("weather")
    For Each oDay In cDays
        Debug.Print oDay.SelectNodes("date")(0).Text
        Debug.Print oDay.SelectNodes("maxtempC")(0).Text
        Debug.Print oDay.SelectNodes("mintempC")(0).Text
        Set cHours = oDay.SelectNodes("hourly")
        For Each oHour In cHours
            Debug.Print vbTab & oHour.SelectNodes("time")(0).Text
            Debug.Print vbTab & oHour.SelectNodes("tempC")(0).Text
            Debug.Print vbTab & oHour.SelectNodes("weatherIconUrl")(0).Text
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: That's true. I implemented XML tree wrong, but I don't expect this will return such error. Thanks for assistance!